# POST with RestKit 0.20 - NSManagedObjectContext issue

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to make a POST request with RestKit, but when I call the *postObject* method of my *RKObjectManager* I get the following error :

```
Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.
```

This error came when the method *performBlockAndWait* is called by the *RKManagedObjectRequestOperation* class.

Here is my code :

```
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 // ...
 }];

NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
NSString *pathPattern = @"myPath";
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:pathPattern keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes];

RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 // ...
 }];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[MyClass class] rootKeyPath:@"" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.1:8080"];
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mySqliteDatabaseFile"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

// POST to create
@try {
    [manager postObject:visitReport path:@"myPath" parameters:nil success:^( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult ) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ){
        NSLog(@"Failure - %@",error);
    }];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"error - %@", exception);
}
```

I don't understand the problem with my context, any help is welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: You're using `postObject` but you don't have any mappings to apply the response to the object that was posted? The posted object is an entity but you want to map back to a dictionary?

Comment: Correct, I didn't have to map back to a dictionary. But I still have the initial error

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I find the problem :

The object visitReport I tried to POST is not from the NSManagedObjectContext expected by RestKit.

To solve, I create a new object :

```
MyObject *visitReportContext = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"tableName" 
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
visitReportContext.Id = visitReport.Id
visitReportContext.title = visitReport.title
// etc..
```

Then, when I POST my new object, it works. But it's not very beautiful... How can I deal with my old object visitReport without create a new one in this "RestKit context" ?